# Поиск k-го наибольшего элемента в массиве

Tags: c++

проблема такая, снизу мой рабочий код, но при вводе +-1 миллионе значений он перестает работать, возможно где-то кроется выход за пределы массива, но я не могу найти этот костыль

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sift(int *arr, int n, int i)
{
    int father = i, left_son, right_son;
    left_son = 2 * i + 1;
    right_son = 2 * i + 2;
    if (left_son < n and arr[left_son] > arr[father])
        father = left_son;
    if (right_son < n and arr[right_son] > arr[father])
        father = right_son;
    if (father != i)
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[father]);
        sift(arr, n, father);
    }
}

void heapSort(int *arr, int n, int k)
{
    int i;
    for (i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        sift(arr, n, i);
    for (i = n - 1; i > n - k - 1; i--)
    {
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        sift(arr, i, 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, k, i;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int arr[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    heapSort(arr, n, k);
    cout << arr[n - k] << " ";
}
```

Comment: А воспользоваться [`nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) не хотите? :) В любом случае сортировка тут не требуется.

Comment: мне нельзя пользоваться такой функцией, решение именно через пирамидку со стопом цикла на k-ой итерации

Comment: Ну, тогда дело другое...

Comment: Как именно перестаёт работать? Ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: то есть в функцию с постройкой пирамиды мне надо передавать значение k + 1, a не n?

Comment: да, ошибка без вывода

Comment: У вас массив в стеке выделяется. Стек переполняется и ага! Работайте с векторами.

Comment: то есть мне лучше создать еще массив длинной k и туда копировать значения до k соответственно? или это никак проблему не решит?

Comment: окей, сейчас попробую вектор сделать

Comment: Вашу текущую проблему исправит замена `int arr[n];` на `std::vector<int> arr(n, 0);`. То что это работает медленнее чем должно - дело другое.

Comment: спасибо огромное!!! помогло) видимо надо привыкать пользоваться векторами в качестве массива

Comment: Не используйте `int arr[n];` если `n` - переменная. Это нестандартное расширение в C++. Которое хорошо выглядит и плохо работает (и именно поэтому не внесено в стандарт).

Comment: приму к сведению, спасибо